# Setting header color for Tabcontrol.Tabpages in winforms. .?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

how to set header color for tabpages in WINFORMS.  and also the back color.

In my code..

```
 For j = 0 To dataset4Category(i).Tables.Count - 1
                    Dim Finder As Integer = Decimal.Floor(((dataset4Category(i).Tables(0).Rows.Count) / 30))
                    key = dataset4Category(i).DataSetName
                    name = Space(1) & StrConv(dataset4Category(i).Tables(0).TableName, VbStrConv.ProperCase) & Space(4)
                    myTabControl.TabPages.Add(key, name)
                    myTabControl.TabPages(j).Tag = 0

                    myTabControl.TabPages(j).BackColor = color.Aqua
                    myTabControl.TabPages(j).BackgroundImage=My.Resources.apple_desktop

                Next
```

In this loop backcolor sets only for the first TAB. Rest is not giving this color.

is there anything wrong..?? How can i set the color for TABPAGES(Dynamically).??

Answer (score 1):

```
// for set header color for tabpages
```

You can set the DrawMode property of your TabControl to "OwnerDrawFixed" and then provide an handler for the DrawItem event

Comment: can i set header color for TABPAGES.   .??